# Does apple crop screen shots for smaller devices?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When submitting an app to the iTunes store, there is an option to use 1 set of images for all iPad or iPhone sizes. ("Use 5.5-inch Display" or "Use 12.9-inch Display") If I click this check box, will it crop my screen shots for smaller devices?

I can't find the answer to this explicitly stated in Apple's documentation.

Comment: Nothing will happen!

Comment: it will not crop screenshots. On apple App Store app full screenshot sizes will be displayed no matter what the iphone/ipad screen size is.